# LDAP Entry-Adding/Installation Error "ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)"

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

I am new to LDAP and am trying to install it for a computer cluster. I have been going through this technical guide https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin26/quickstart.html.
I have reached step 11 and am now adding test users to the directory. I have created the `.ldif` files in my home directory with the same text as the guide stated, the only difference being replacing the DC's (I have three of them instead of two), the `o: Example Company` line (I replaced it with the name of our cluster), and the `dc: Example` line with the first of our DC's.  The text below is directly from the guide.

```
objectclass: dcObject
objectclass: organization
o: Example Company
dc: example

dn: cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: organizationalRole
cn: Manager
```

The next step is to run the ldapadd command.
`ldapadd -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com" -W -f example.ldif`.
I replaced the file names and DC's with the corresponding correct ones, but once I run the command I am prompted to enter a password (`Enter LDAP Password:` ) and am met with this error: `ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)`.

The guide does not explicitly mention something of this sort. I have tried installing LDAP a couple of times previously and had set up the password, but each of those times I ended up attempting to uninstall the software and corresponding files as I encountered other errors. I believe that this password conflict may be because of these previous installations not being entirely uninstalled, but am not sure. I made note of these passwords and have attempted to enter it many, many times, but it still marks what I enter as incorrect. I have tried changing the password as well using `slappasswd`, but this new password still gives the same error as well. I cannot find any other commands either that seem to be relevant, and am not sure as to what my next step should be.

I appreciate any and all help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should have set a `rootpw` entry in your `slapd` configuration. Is that the password you're entering when prompted?

Comment: And does the `rootdn` in your configuration match the dn with which you are authenticating?

Comment: The `rootpw` entry just has "`secret`" listed after it. I have tried this as well but it gives the same error. Additionally, should I edit the rootdn in the `slapd.conf` file if it is not the same as the entries which I am adding? I am not 100% sure how to check if the dn's are the same.

Comment: You use the `rootdn` and `rootpw` to initially connect to your slapd instance. They don't need to match the entries you're adding (you can configure access control information in LDAP to permit other users to authenticate and access information).

Comment: I still seem to be having issues. Would you be able to further specify how to check if the `rootdn` matches with the dn that I am authenticating?

Comment: (a) look at the `rootdn` in your configuration. (b) look at the argument you're providing to `-D`. Do they match?

Comment: The `rootdn` in my slapd.conf file has `"cn=root,dc=physics,dc=college,dc=edu"`. The arguments I pass with the `ldapadd` command are `"cn=Manager,dc=physics,dc=college,dc=edu"`. They do match except for the cn, which I thought could differ.

Comment: Two distinguished names that are not identical are not the same DN. "CN=alice,..." is the same person as "CN=bob,...".

Comment: I see. Thank you for the clarification. I made the `rootdn` instead to have `cn=Manager`, so that it matches the argument I input with the ldapadd command, but I am met with the same error. Would it be necessary to provide the password hash into the `olcRootPW` line of the slapd.ldif file, as I did into the `rootpw` line of the slapd.conf file?

Comment: I think we've reached the limits of what we can accomplish in comments. I would suggest *starting over*, making sure that you follow the quickstart *exactly* (don't change name or passwords). Once you've got it working correctly, *then* start trying to modify things.

Comment: I too think that that would be a reasonable step forward. Thank you for all your help so far, I greatly appreciate it.